# Error when reading blank cell in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, null, cell

I'm reading data from an Excel workbook in a C# app using the Excel.dll. After reading each row, I add that row to a DataTable. When I come across a blank cell, the app crashes, throwing the following error:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here's the loop in which this crash occurs:

```
foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows.Skip(1))
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    int cellNumber = 0;
    foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cellNumber++;
        if (cellNumber > 6)
            break;
        switch (cell.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                dr["BatchID"] = cell.Value;
                break;
            case 1:
                dr["RecID"] = cell.Value;
                break;
            case 2:
                dr["Rejection"] = cell.Value;
                break;
            case 3:
                dr["Comment"] = cell.Value;
                break;
            case 4:
                dr["Logged"] = double.Parse(cell.Value);
                break;
            case 5:
                dr["Modified"] = cell.Value;
                break;
        }
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

This is all within a TRY/CATCH block. Everything runs fine on the first input row (which has no blank cells), but on the second input row (where the fourth cell is blank), it reads the first three cells, then crashes on the SWITCH line, going into my CATCH block.

How can I see if the current cell is blank or null so I can avoid this error?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you please update with your full stack trace.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at ReadExcelWorksheet.Program.ReadWorksheet(DataTable dt, String excelInput) in ::\Projects\ReadExcelWorksheet\Program.cs:line 64

Comment: Looking at the your error message, Akos is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `foreach`, after your `if - break` statement, you could simply add a null check:

```
if (cell==null)
{
  continue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Akos! I tried several other things yesterday, that were much more involved. Great to see a simple solution. Much appreciated!

Comment: Happy to help :)